# JSF ui repeat : Array index out of range: 0

Tags: jsf, arraylist, uirepeat

i have form inside my form i have ui repeat wich repeat input form i want to save value of input text in my bean :

```
<ui:repeat var="field" value="#{formSettings.studentsFormSettings}" varStatus="form"> 
  <h:inputText required="#{field.valdaite}" 
    requiredMessage="#{field.requrid}" disabled="#{!field.active}" 
    rendered="#{field.type eq 'TEXT'}" value="#{formData.data[form.index]}"> </h:inputText> 
</ui:repeat>
```

---

I created bean has list of value

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
    public class FormData {

        private List<String> data;

    // setter and getter 

    }
```

I got error :

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /text.xhtml @23,78 value="#{formData.data[form.index]}": Array index out of range: 0
```

Comment: Try to initialize `data = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: i already have it 

 @PostConstruct
 public void initChoices() {
  data = new ArrayList<String>();
 }

Comment: But also put 1 record in there! (or make sure studentsFormSettings does not return anything (an empty list))